# Query on GNU Radio Companion Threshold block and Selector Block

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

Dipping my feet into the waters of SDR and am stuck with my first flowchart.

I wanted to create a flowchart in which I detect an external signal from a  RTL-SDR Source block and then switch off a signal to the USRP sink created using the Signal Source block.
The signal is detected using the Threshold block but how do I control the Signal source block from the outputs of the Threshold block directly without using any python scripts?
I tried to use a 2*1 (2 inputs, one output)  selector block, one fed with a null source and the other with the wanted signal but the  'iindex' Input index can only be messaged and cannot be controlled by the threshold block directly? Can someone provide some advice?
The flowchart is attached below........I cannot seem to connect any outputs (red arrow) to the 'iindex' Input index so that the selector could be switched between the wanted source and the null source.
Not familiar with Python so am not sure if I can write a block for it.

'iindex' Input index can only be messaged and cannot be controlled by the threshold block directly

[image: Flowchart is here]

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use a sample stream (here: a complex-valued one, as signified by the blue color of the output) as a message input (the grey ports).

I'd remove the "float to complex" and instead just "Multiply" the output of your "Signal Source" with the output of "Threshold".

Furthermore, you cannot have unconnected blocks in your flowgraph (The two up top).

This feels like you might not have come very far in the GNU Radio [official tutorials](https://tutorials.gnuradio.org). Maybe refresh them a bit (we tried to make them work in the order as listed on that tutorial overview page, so I'd recommend going through them in that order).